# Can i rob Peter to pay Paul

Tags: weed-control

I have a Ryobi string trimmer that is used for attachments. But the Ryobi needs rebuilt. Which, i could do. But wanted to know if I could remove the clutch from the Ryobi, and install it on a weed wacker that I already have rebuilt? The weed wacker i have already rebuilt is a Bolens. (BL100) im wondering if it would support the Ryobi clutch?

Comment: This is one of those "it depends" answer.  It might work but if it did you would not be able to get service on it as it is using parts from two units.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, after looking at them further, what you are saying is correct. I just dont think a clutch swap is possible. Ill just rebuild the Ryobi. No big. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If they share the same parts, then yes. I have a Cub Cadet, which is made by MTD, who also makes many others including Craftsman, Yard-Machine, some Ryobi etc. It would depend on the model and year. You can use a parts lookup site to determine if the parts are compatible. Then if you want to swap them, go for it. But since you will be tearing them apart, why not search the likes of ebay or amazon for parts that might be less than you expect and put new stuff in?